# How to install joomla in our local computer

Tags: joomla

how to install joomla in our computer. what is configuration requirement for installing the joomla in computer.

Comment: This isn't really a programming question. Perhaps you should ask over at http://superuser.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using windows, you might want to look at the [Microsoft Web Platform Installer](http://www.microsoft.com/web/downloads/platform.aspx).
You can easily install Joomla! this way, including all other prerequisites for running it on your local machine.

When you launch installer, Joomla! can be found under Web Applications -> Content Management.

Answer (score 2):

If you are not terribly familiar with how web servers fit together (it is easier than you think), you may want to try a Bitnami stack.  You can download an entire Joomla stack from http://bitnami.org/stack/joomla

The joy of Bitnami is that you can run one installation package and install Joomla plus everything that you need to run it (ie - Apache, mySQL, PHP!)

Answer (score 0):

First download the joomla 1.0 or joomla 1.5 what you want then 
On your Xammp sever in htdocs paste the joomla folder and then browse in browser
http://localhost/joomla(folder name).
follow the link:[Joomla installation](http://www.joomlatemplatestyle.com/1.5_Installation_Manual_version_0.4.pdf)

Any more informatioin need?

Answer (score 0):

To install Joomla, you need to be running a webserver of some sort.

You can download one of these for free - I use http://www.wampserver.com/ but http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp.html is also fine.

Once you have installed it, you then need to download and unzip the Joomla install into the root of the server. You will then need to go through the installation process. This will ask you to setup a database (use phpmyadmin or similar).

Assuming you get through all of that, you're ready to go!

Answer (score 0):

If you have a web server in your local pc, it's half done. If not' then download Wamp or Xampp servers and install in your pc. IIS is also a fine option. 
After that create a directory in your local host and copy the downloaded files from joomla download setup into the directory. Now browse to the location via browser, and the package will automatically prompt you to supply basic configuration values like db details and admin details . Once done with this, you need to remove the install directory from the joomla root directory., and you are done.